# PHP implode with Farsi(persian) text is in wrong order

Tags: php, right-to-left, implode

The below code outputs farsi text in the wrong order.  `$arr[2]` should be at the end but it is in the middle?

```
            $arr= array();
            $arr[0]= 'title';
            $arr[1]= 'محمد رضا گلزار‎، الناز شاکردوست';
            $arr[2] = 'مجنون لیلی';


            $string = implode(" - ",$arr);
            echo $string;
```

Output:

```
title - محمد رضا گلزار‎، الناز شاکردوست - مجنون لیلی
```

I've also tried to concatenate like this and same result.

```
echo $arr[0].' - '.$arr[1].' - '.$arr[2];
```

How do i solve? `$arr[2]` should be last.  This also isn't a consistent error, if i use different farsi text, i get desired result.

Comment: I think it is the browser display.  Maybe you have `dir="rtl"` and so it's reversing it but it's already in the order you want.  Not sure but probably related.

Comment: I believe the problem is after the grapheme `مح`, after which the ltr direction is changed using Unicode. You'll notice that selecting the text by drawing a box using the mouse results in some weird behaviour.